# На фейсбуку чи на фейсбуці? У ноутбуку чи в ноутбуці?

Tags: відмінювання, чергування

Питання про чергування літери `к` у місцевому відмінку.

[Професор Пономарів](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2013/11/131125_ponomariv_blog_ko) каже наступне:

Тут можливі обидві форми: на *Фейсбуці* і на *Фейсбуку*.

На [словниках україни онлайн](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) шукаю схожі слова:

Друк - у *друці* / *друку*. Звук - у *звуці*.

Скажіть, будь ласка, чи можна це врегулювати з граматичної точки зору, чи дійсно можна користуватися обома варіантами написання і не зважати на "правильність"?

Суб’єктивно:

Мені подобається відмінювати навіть іноземні слова на український манер – з чергуванням, але не хотілося б робити це неправильно.